# Way to prove this relationship without using actual values of cos and tan. arctan(cosu) =?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

The problem is $\arctan(\cos u) = ?$
I think for this I need to find an angle answer in relation to $u$.
So I think of a triangle where

$\cos u = x$ and so $\tan v = x$

since we need the angle $v$ such that the tan of it is $\;= \cos u = x$

I then divided $u$ by $v$ to get

$$\frac{u}{v} = \frac{\arccos(x)}{\arctan(x)}$$

An x value that $\arccos$ and $\arctan$ have in common is $-1$.

$$\frac{u}{v} = \frac{\arccos(-1)}{\arctan(-1)} = \frac{\pi}{\frac{-\pi}{4}} = -4$$ and because $\frac{u}{v} = -4$ then $v = \frac{-u}{4}$ This is the relationship and I believe this is the answer $$\arctan(\cos u) = \frac{-u}{4}$$ I am not sure if this is correct or not, are these steps valid? Also is there a way to do this without plugging in values like $x = -1$  and keeping it purely with variables or something like that?

Comment: To check your solution just try one value, e.g. $u=0$.

Comment: If you plot $\arctan(\cos u)$ you’ll see immediately that it’s non-linear.

Comment: I see, I just plotted it on desmos.com. Can you think of any way to related them if not linear? It looks like a cosine type function to me